# Laplace transform second shifting rule

Tags: laplace-transform

I have found seccond shifting rules with and without the Heaviside function.
Even my professor taught us the one without Heaviside.

For example if $f(t)=2e^-e(t-3)$

1)Rewrite this expression as $2L\{e^{-3t}e^9\}$ and get the answer $\frac{(2e^9)}{(S+3)}$

2)Use the second shifting theorem: $L\{f(t-a)\}=e^{-at}F(S)$ and get the answer
$\frac{2e^{-3s}}{S+3}$

As far as i know, every function has only one Laplace transform and vice-versa.

Is the theorem without Heaviside function wrong? Can you explain in simple terms, how does exactly the heaviside function affect the Laplace transform?
Why is multiplication with Heaviside function necessary?

Comment: what ? you want help proving why $L\{f(t-a)\}(s) = \int_{a}^\infty f(t-a) e^{-st} dt = \int_{0}^\infty f(t) e^{-s(t+a)} dt = e^{-sa} \int_{0}^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt = e^{-sa} L\{f(t)\}(s)$

Comment: and not every functions have a Laplace transform, for example $f(t) = e^{t^2}\ _{t \ge 0}$ doesn't have, it is because it is not bounded by $A e^{C t}$ for any $C$

Comment: I know the first proof, but i need to know if my professor is teaching me wrong facts?

Comment: what facts ? write your question clearly, and look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: Is the second shifting theorem true, as i wrote it? Or does the original function f(t-a) have to be multiplied by u(t-a)?